# Needing multiple where clauses or a better way of conditional statement

Tags: sql, t-sql, conditional-statements

I'm trying to figure out how to show data in one table based on if a value doesn't exist in another table. I've researched case statements and couldn't figure out how it would apply in my current situation.

I have two tables, `CompanyRequestOff` and `TakeOver` and I want to be able to select columns from `CompanyRequestOff` where `TransactionID`s are equal BUT the `User` column cannot be the same.

Any help even pointing me in the right direction would be useful thank you.

The `CompanyRequestOff` table has these columns:

```
TransactionID
Requestee
RequestedDate
RequestedTimeSlot
RequestedPosition
RequestStatus
LastUpdate
Manager
```

And the `TakeOver` table has:

```
Id
TransactionID
RequestedUser
RequestStatus
LastUpdate
Manager
```

This is my attempt at solving this:

```
SELECT
    CompanyRequestOff.TransactionID, CompanyRequestOff.Requestee,
    CompanyRequestOff.RequestedDate, CompanyRequestOff.RequestedTimeSlot,
    CompanyRequestOff.RequestedTimeSlot, CompanyRequestOff.RequestedPosition,
    CompanyRequestOff.RequestStatus, CompanyRequestOff.LastUpdate, 
    CompanyRequestOff.Manager 
FROM
    CompanyRequestOff, TakeOver 
WHERE
    RequestedDate > GETDATE() 
    AND CompanyRequestOff.RequestStatus = 'Requested' 
    AND CompanyRequestOff.TransactionID = TakeOver.TransactionID  
    AND TakeOver.RequestedUser != @UserN;
```

The only column that is related is the `transactionID` column which is primary in `CompanyRequestOff` and Foreign in `TakeOver`. I would like to display the columns that are in the `CompanyRequestOff` table where there is no row in `TakeOver` with that `transactionID` BUT only if it contains a certain `TakeOver.RequestedUser` value.

Comment: Can't it just be a compound condition on the join? `Select * from CompanyRequestOff CRO LEFT JOIN takeOver TO on TO.TransactionID = CRO.TransactionID and CRO.User <> TO.User`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to `join` these two tables under two conditions:

```
SELECT *
FROM CompanyRequestOff CRO
JOIN TakeOver TO on TO.TransactionID = CRO.TransactionID and TO.User <> CRO.User
```

Update to account for your edits:

> I would like to display the columns that are in the CompanyRequestOff
>   table where There is no row in TakeOver with that transactionID BUT
>   only if it contains a certain TakeOver.RequestedUser value.

You can achieve the transactionID part of this with a `where transactionID not in` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM CompanyRequestOff
WHERE TransactionID not in 
     (SELECT TransactionID FROM TakeOver)
```

Then add in the User part:

```
SELECT *
FROM CompanyRequestOff
WHERE TransactionID not in 
    (SELECT TransactionID FROM TakeOver WHERE RequestedUser <> @UserN)
```

And with all your logic from your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM CompanyRequestOff
WHERE TransactionID not in 
    (SELECT TransactionID FROM TakeOver WHERE RequestedUser <> @UserN)
AND RequestedDate > GETDATE()
AND RequestStatus = 'Requested'
```

Comment: This doesn't display data for me since this shows me where the User values are the same where as I'd like to see where they are different. The TakeOver user and CompanyRequestOff user are in no way a relation to eachother.

Comment: This worked! the only thing was i had to change the <> '@UserN' to = '@UserN' cause your way included the TransactionIDs with that username but this helped me so much thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your question, it seems like you have two common columns between `CompanyRequestOff` and `TakeOver` - `User` and `TransactionID`. So, your query should be such that you select all the records from `CompanyRequestOff` where `TransactionID` is matching but `user` is not matching.

```
select c.* from CompanyRequestOff c, TakeOver t
where c.TransactionId = t.TransactionId 
and c.user != t.user
```